# VBA code in excel runs slow on Activate event in worksheet. Need to improve performance please

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I am trying to protect rows, set dropdown list dynamically on Worksheet_Activate event but my code for 1000 rows takes 15 mins to open the worksheet as it keeps spinning. When I switch between tabs I want to be able to set the dropdowns, disable rows and set color on the rows.Can you tell  how I can improve the performance of the worksheet while being able to achieve the mentioned objective.?

```
     Sub DisableOsIs()

        On Error Resume Next

        Dim NoOfDataRows As Integer
        Dim RngOP, RngIL, RngL, RngM, RngN, RngO, RngP, RngQ, RngR, RngLockAll As Range
        Dim cell As Range
        'ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="1234"
        'Set NoOfDataRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Set RngOP = Range("P5:P" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        Set RngIL = Range("I5:I" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        Set RngL = Range("L5:L" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        Set RngM = Range("M5:M" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        Set RngN = Range("N5:N" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        Set RngO = Range("O5:O" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        Set RngP = Range("P5:P" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        Set RngQ = Range("Q5:Q" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        Set RngR = Range("R5:R" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
        Set RngLockAll = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1 & ":R" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1000)


        Call SetLEDWattageList(RngL) 
        Call SetColorTemperatureList(RngM) 
        Call SetLShield(RngN) 
        Call SetRemoveSLModifyAList(RngO) 
        Call SetRemoveSLModifyAList(RngP) 
        Call SetALengthList(RngQ) 
        Call SetArmDModList(RngR)
        Call DisableLED(RngIL)  
        Call LockAll(RngLockAll)



        End Sub


    Sub LockAll(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="1234"

    With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)
           .Locked = True
     End With

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="1234"

    End Sub

    Sub SetLEDWattageList(ByVal Target As Range)

     With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)
           .Locked = False
            With .Validation
                .Delete
                'replace "=A1:A6" with the range the data is in.
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=listone!D2:D5"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
     End With

    End Sub

    Sub SetColorTemperatureList(ByVal Target As Range)

     With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)
            .Locked = False
            With .Validation
                .Delete
                'replace "=A1:A6" with the range the data is in.
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=listone!E2:E3"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
     End With

    End Sub

    Sub SetLShield(ByVal Target As Range)

     With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)
            .Locked = False
            With .Validation
                .Delete
                'replace "=A1:A6" with the range the data is in.
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=listone!A2:A4"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
     End With

    End Sub

    Sub SetRemoveSLModifyAList(ByVal Target As Range)

     With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)
            .Locked = False
            With .Validation
                .Delete
                'replace "=A1:A6" with the range the data is in.
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=listone!I2:I3"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
     End With

    End Sub

    Sub SetALengthList(ByVal Target As Range)

     With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)
            .Locked = False
            With .Validation
                .Delete
                'replace "=A1:A6" with the range the data is in.
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=listone!F2:F4"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
     End With

    End Sub
    Sub SetArmDModList(ByVal Target As Range)

     With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)
            .Locked = False
            With .Validation
                .Delete
                'replace "=A1:A6" with the range the data is in.
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=listone!G2:G9"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
     End With

    End Sub

'I am passing in a range and checking if the value is LED and color the 'successive columns and protect them.
Sub DisableLED(ByVal Target As Range)
 On Error Resume Next


 'Check if Target cell in the "Make a selection" range is changed
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I5:O" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)) Is Nothing Then
'    ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False
        If Target.Value = "LED" Then
         ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="1234" 
            'Dropdown and error message on cells 2 and 3 columns left of "Make a selection" will be enabled
            With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1)
                 .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
                 '.Value = vbNullString
            End With
            With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 2)
                 .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
                 '.Value = vbNullString
            End With
            With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 3)
                 .Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                 .Value = vbNullString

                With .Validation
                .InCellDropdown = False
                .ShowError = False
                End With

            End With

           With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 4)
                 .Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                 .Value = vbNullString

              With .Validation
                .InCellDropdown = False
                .ShowError = False
              End With

           End With


           With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 5)
                 .Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                 .Value = vbNullString
               With .Validation
                .InCellDropdown = False
                .ShowError = False
               End With

           End With

             With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 6)
                 .Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                 .Value = vbNullString

               With .Validation
                  .InCellDropdown = False
                  .ShowError = False
                End With

            End With

             With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 7)
                 .Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
                 .Value = vbNullString

                    With .Validation
                .InCellDropdown = False
                .ShowError = False
                End With

            End With

             With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 8)
                 .Interior.Color = RGB(221, 217, 196)
                 .Value = vbNullString

                    With .Validation
                .InCellDropdown = False
                .ShowError = False
                End With

            End With

              With Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 9)
                 .Interior.Color = RGB(221, 217, 196)
                 .Value = vbNullString

                    With .Validation
                .InCellDropdown = False
                .ShowError = False
                End With

            End With


            Target.Locked = False
            'Range(Target.Row & ":" & Target.Column).Cells.Locked = False
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Locked = True
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 2).Locked = True
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 3).Locked = True
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 4).Locked = True
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 5).Locked = True
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 6).Locked = True
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 7).Locked = True
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 8).Locked = True
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 9).Locked = True
            ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="1234"  'Contents:=True, DrawingObjects:=False 

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Too much code here.  From a quick look I'd say stop doing everything cell-by-cell and operate on the whole range at once.  For example pass the whole `rngL` to `SetLEDWattageList` instead of passing one cell at a time.

Comment: Hi Tim.  I am trying to set different dropdown list in each of those ranges, that is why I was iterating through it cell by cell. if I call :  Call SetLEDWattageList(RngL) How do I rewrite the SetLEDWattageList method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tim, I have reduced the code size and reformatted the code passing in the range. Let me know please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first glance, your code does not need the functions you call loosing time calling them cell by cell. For instance, the first three calls can be replaced, making the code more efficient, by simple doing that:

```
 Dim RngIL As Range, RngM As Range, RngN As Range, lastRow As Long
 Dim sh As Worksheet
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'You have to define sh according to your sheet name
 sh.Unprotect "1234"
 lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

  Set RngIL = sh.Range("I5:I" & lastRow): RngIL.Locked = False
   With RngIL.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=listone!D$2:D$5"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
  End With

  Set RngM = sh.Range("M5:M" & lastRow): RngM.Locked = False
   With RngM.Validation
      .Delete
      .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=listone!E$2:E$3"
      .IgnoreBlank = True
      .InCellDropdown = True
      .InputTitle = ""
      .ShowInput = True
      .ShowError = True
   End With

   Set RngN = sh.Range("N5:N" & lastRow): RngN.Locked = False
    With RngM.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=listone!A$2:A$4"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

    'do here the locking procedure if you consider it makes sense...
    sh.Protect "1234"

    'and so on for all ranges where you must change their cells in the same way...
```

And a simpler/shorter piece of code doing the same, but un-protecting the sheet:

```
Sub testSimplified()
 Dim RngIL As Range, RngM As Range, RngN As Range, lastRow As Long, cel As Range
 Dim sh As Worksheet
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'You have to define sh according to your sheet name
 sh.Unprotect "1234"
 lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
  Set RngIL = sh.Range("I5:I" & lastRow): RngIL.Locked = False
    ChangeValidation RngIL, "=listone!D$2:D$5"

  Set RngM = sh.Range("M5:M" & lastRow): RngM.Locked = False
    ChangeValidation RngM, "=listone!E$2:E$3"

   Set RngN = sh.Range("N5:N" & lastRow): RngN.Locked = False
     ChangeValidation RngN, "=listone!A$2:A$4"

   'do here the locking procedure...
   For Each cel In RngIL
        If cel.value = "LED" Then
            DisableLED cel, sh
        End If
   Next
   sh.Protect "1234"
End Sub
Sub ChangeValidation(rng As Range, strCondition As String)
    With rng.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=strCondition
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
Sub DisableLED(ByVal Target As Range, sh As Worksheet)
    With sh.Range(Target.Offset(0, 1).Address & ":" & Target.Offset(0, 2).Address)
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
    End With
    With sh.Range(Target.Offset(0, 3).Address & ":" & Target.Offset(0, 7).Address)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
        .Validation.Delete
    End With
    With sh.Range(Target.Offset(0, 8).Address & ":" & Target.Offset(0, 9).Address)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(221, 217, 196)
        .Validation.Delete
    End With
    sh.Range(Target.Offset(0, 1).Address & ":" & Target.Offset(0, 9).Address).Locked = True
End Sub
```

You must take care of making the validation range absolute (using '$' in front of the validation range row)...
A even better way would be to use named ranges.
No need of un-protect in the called sub due to the fact that the sheet has been un-protected at the beginning of the code.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204949/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-vba-code-in-excel-runs-slow-on-activate-event-i).